# Common Event For Datagridview which is invoked in both case of rowHeaderWidth or ColumnWidthChanged is changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any common event for datagridview which is fired, when ***rowHeaderWidth*** of datagridview is changed or ***column Width*** of datagridview is changed?

I have used ***datagridview.ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)*** it is invoked when ***column width*** is changed but it is not invoked when ***row header width*** of the datagridview is changed.

I have also used ***dataGridView1_RowHeadersWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)*** it is invoked when ***row header width*** is changed but it is not invoked when ***column width*** of the datagridview is changed.

So I want a common event which is invoked in both case...

Comment: For both Web and WinForm DataGridView Control?

Comment: Only for winform, but this common event should be invoked in both case like column width is changed or row header width is changed..

Comment: Ah, my bad, I've no idea why I read the tag as 'asp.net'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated code using both:
- `ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)`
- `RowHeadersWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Column Width Changed");
    widthChanged(sender, e);
}

private void dataGridView1_RowHeadersWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Row Header Width Changed");
    widthChanged(sender, null);
}

private void widthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Any Width Changed");
}
```

Works when I resized either header's column width or item's column width.

Comment: Here,header's column is not the column header,but the row header means the header of the row.

Comment: I see. Looks like there's no generic event for both, I've improvised by using the updated the code above.

Comment: Ok Thank You it will work.. But is not there any common event for both?

Comment: I double so, unless you want to track the form's onmousedown and detect user is performing width resizing. To me, that's one heck of a tedious task.